# Manage wordpress blog on remote server via git

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control

I want to be able to develop my plugins & themes on my machine and the changes be reflected on my server almost instantly. Also I want a backup plan. So git & github seems a very good solution. I want to make regular changes to the server (push from local) and once in a while upload them on github too (local to github or remote to github).

The question is can I clone the repo from github to my remote server and to my local machine and be able to push from local to remote or pull from github to remote (if I'm not at home)?

Edit: I did a research and I found out that I actually need a bare repo in the server, but i want it to be able to push/pull to/from github.

Answer (score 2):

In github and bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org) you can add any number of ssh keys from different machines and push and pull from anywhere you want. The command to generate such a key is

```
ssh-keygen
```

answer the questions with enter and the ssh key will be in `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. You have to do this for every machine you want to push and when the repository is set to private, yo also have to do it for those machines, you want to pull from.

So the workflow would be

- editing locally
- pushing to github/butbucket repo: `git push -u origin`
- log in to the machine where wordpress is running: `git pull`

Comment: I know that. The problem is that I get error when I try to push directly to the remote server from the local machine.

Comment: So you do not want to use github? A direct push to your machine where Wordpress is running only works if there is a git client running there. However you would not need any additional repo-system like github or bitbucket. Could you clarify?

Comment: I want to be able to push/pull from my local machine to github and to my server. I also want to push/pull to github directly from my server

Comment: Honestly, that does not make too much sense to me but maybe I am still missing a point. Why would you run two different git hosts when you only work with one repo? How would you keep track of which pushes you made to github resp. to the server directly? I can only suggest to do it the way scetched above, sorry.

Comment: Because I don't want to push to github from local and pull from the server for each change